# Zoom with background drag in force layout with arc link in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3.js, so please help me with the issue. Zoom feature is working while mouseover on node, not on the background and draging of  background is also not working in force layout with arc link of d3.js. Here is the sample [jsfiddle project](http://jsfiddle.net/aVhd8/297/) , i have created. I have seen [example](http://jsfiddle.net/blt909/aVhd8/20/) where background can be dragged.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoomed);
var links = graph.links;
var nodes = graph.nodes;
svg.call(zoom);
 svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["publishedBy", "publishedOn", "depicts","postedOn","childOf"])
  .enter().append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");


links.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.source > b.source) {return 1;}
    else if (a.source < b.source) {return -1;}
    else {
        if (a.target > b.target) {return 1;}
        if (a.target < b.target) {return -1;}
        else {return 0;}
    }
});

for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0 &&
        links[i].source == links[i-1].source &&
        links[i].target == links[i-1].target) {
            links[i].linknum = links[i-1].linknum + 1;
        }
    else {links[i].linknum = 1;};
};


var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(links).enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "link")
.append("line")
.attr("class", "link-line")
.style("stroke-width", 1);

 var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
.origin(function(d) { return d; })
.on("dragstart", dragstarted)
.on("drag", dragged)
.on("dragend", dragended);


var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes).enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("r", 20)
 .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
.style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.type); })
.on("mouseover", mouseover)
.on("mouseout", mouseout)
.call(drag);
```

Comment: Just from a cursory glance, it looks like you're missing the container element that both the example you give and Mike's drag and zoom example have: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

Comment: Container object contains nothing but svg element, i am rather using svg object. I don't think Container obj really matters here. If it really matters then other example which i have mentioned there also container object is not used but background drag is working fine. Only difference i observed that, link is arced in my example and in other example it's straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated the svg object and added the overlay style, now i can zoom on the background and draging of background is also working. updated the 
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ram140488/aVhd8/302/) mentioned the question.

```
 svg.append("rect").attr("class", "overlay").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

.overlay {fill: none; height="500";  width="1200"; pointer-events: all;}
```